# Retrieve data from JSON using another JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, request

Firstly, cities.json has cities info inside, retrieve the info, add to HTML, easy. Harder task is to use cities.json with list of cities ONLY = ["New York", "London", "..."] etc. and specific city info being stored in New York.json, London.json etc. How to retrieve the data from New York.json using cities.json?

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('get', `cities.json`);
request.responseType = "json";
request.onload = () => {
    let show = document.getElementById("box");
    for (let object of request.response) {
        box.innerHTML += `<p>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/${object.name}">${object.name}</a>
<br>
population: ${object.population}
<br>
area: ${object.area}
</p>`;
    }
}
request.send();

New York.json = 
[
    {
        "name": "New York",
        "population": some integer,
        "area": some integer
    },
]
```

Comment: The object is inside an array, `let object of request.response[0]` would list the first city. If there are more cities, you need to iterate the wrapper array, and nest the current code in the iteration loop (with the index added like shown earlier in this comment).

Answer (score 0):

1. Suppose you have a site folder with content:

- index.html
- cities.json {"cities": ["newYork", "london"]}
- newYork.json {"name": "New York", "population": 999, "area": 232 }
- london.json {"name": "London", "population": 999, "area": 232 }
- ...

2. You have to find an application server to serve the folder on some port:

   Example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/light-server

   Command: light-server -s . -p 8000

   Browser: http://localhost:8000 will render index.html
3. You can use also fetch to send HTTP requests and receive responses.

---

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <div id="data"></div>
    <script>
        function render(city, data) {
            let name = data.name;
            let population = data.population;
            let element = document.createElement("div");
            element.innerHTML = city + "=> name:" + name + ", population: " + population
            document.getElementById("data").append(element);
        }
        fetch("/cities.json").then(response => {
            response.json().then(json => {
                let cities = json.cities;
                cities.forEach(city => {
                    fetch("/" + city + ".json").then(cityResponse => {
                        cityResponse.json().then(cityJson => {
                            render(city, cityJson)
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="data"></div>
  <script>
    function render(city, data) {
      let name = data.name;
      let population = data.population;
      let element = document.createElement("div");
      element.innerHTML = city + "=> name:" + name + ", population: " + population
      document.getElementById("data").append(element);
    }
    let citiesRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    citiesRequest.onload = function () {
      let json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      let cities = json.cities;
      cities.forEach(city => {
        let cityRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        cityRequest.onload = function () {
          let cityJson = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          render(city, cityJson);
        }
        cityRequest.open("GET", "/" + city + ".json", true);
        cityRequest.send();
      })
    }
    citiesRequest.open("GET", "/cities.json", true);
    citiesRequest.send();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The best would method in my case would be not using the fetch but will give it a try, thanks!

Comment: I added also XMLHttpRequest version.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for the effort, you're a lifesaver!